# AVPlayer Video Get and Set Volume for a UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, avplayer

We're using AVPlayer in an app to do some playback of some embedded videos and need to implement a UISlider for the volume. What's a good way to read the current volume and set the current volume for this playback?

Note, I'm trying to link this to the system sound.

Comment: You will want to implement MPVolumeView.  Check out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html